# What is the difference between upconversion and two-photon absorption?

Tags: photons

I thought that two-photon absorption is the underlying mechanism of upconversion, but according to Wikipedia ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_upconversion), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-photon_absorption)),

> Upconversion should be distinguished from two-photon absorption [...]

and

> Two-photon absorption (TPA) is the simultaneous absorption of two
>   photons of identical or different frequencies in order to excite a
>   molecule from one state (usually the ground state) to a higher energy
>   electronic state.

So what's exactly the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These terms are the beginning and the end of the process that you're thinking about. Lets look at examples where they don't occur together, to see the distinction.

1. A photon excites an electron from A to B. Later, another excites the electron from B to C. If the electron then drops from C to A, the resulting photon is higher energy than either incident photon. This is upconversion, but not TPA, because the photons did not arrive at the same time (and state B is a real state).
2. Two low energy photons excite an electron from A to B. The electron doesn't drop down, but instead a voltage is used to ionize it (from B to infinity). The ionization is easier because of the TPA that happened. Upconversion is not happening here.

I hope this makes the distinction clear. Upconversion is *only* the emission of a higher frequency photon, and TPA is *only* the simultaneous absorption of two photons.